# Spring 5 Validator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have User class So I created `UserValidator.java` using Validator interface of Spring for validation of User while registration.

Problem is that validations are applied successfully but jsp page does not show the error messages.

UserValidator.java

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
     return User.class.equals(clazz);
}

public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "userName", "Enter a valid name");
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "address", " Enter Address");
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "mobNo", "Enter valid mobile number");
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "emailId", "Enter a valid email");

      User user = (User) obj;
      System.out.println(""+user.getUserName());
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$",
              Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        if (!(pattern.matcher(user.getEmailId()).matches())) {
            errors.rejectValue("emailId", "Invalid email! Please enter valid email");
        }

}}
```

RegistrationController.java

```
@Controller
 public class RegistrationController {
 @Autowired
  UserValidator userValidator;

 @InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder){
        webDataBinder.setValidator(userValidator);
 }

@Autowired
private DepartmentDao departmentDao;  

@Autowired
private DesignationDao designationDao;

@Autowired
private ConfigDao configDao;

@Autowired
private HintQuestionDao hintQuestionDao;

@Autowired
private GroupDao groupDao;

 @Autowired
 private UserDao userDao;

@RequestMapping("Register")
public String getRegisterPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {

      model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentDao.getDepartments());
      model.addAttribute("designationList", designationDao.getDesignation());
      model.addAttribute("levelList", configDao.getLevel());
      model.addAttribute("questionList",hintQuestionDao.getQuestions());
      model.addAttribute("groupList", groupDao.getGroup());
      return "Registration";
}

@RequestMapping("newRegisterUser")
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model,@RequestParam("deptId") int deptid,
@RequestParam("desgId") int desgId,@RequestParam("grpId")int grpId,HttpSession session, BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception{
    User userSess= (User) session.getAttribute("userObj");
      if(userSess!=null) {

          userValidator.validate(user, bindingResult);
          if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

                 return "redirect:Register";
          }
      user.setMobNo(user.getMobNo());
      user.setDepartment(departmentDao.getDepartmentById(deptid));
      user.setDesignation(designationDao.getDesignationById(desgId));
      user.setGroup(groupDao.getGroupById(grpId));
      user.setUpw1(user.getUserName().replace(" " , "").substring(0,4)+user.getEmailId().substring(0,2)+"#"+user.getMobNo().toString().substring(8));
      user.setCreatedBy(userSess.getUserName());
      user.setCreationDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
      user.setLoginStatus("A");
          userDao.createUser(user);
      }
      else {
          model.addAttribute("AddMessage","Login First");
      }
      return "redirect:ListOfUser";
}}
```

Registration.jsp

```html
<form:form class="form" modelAttribute="user" method="post" action="newRegisterUser">
              
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Name:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-9">
                          <form:input class="form-control" type="text" path="userName"/>
                         <form:errors path = "userName" cssClass = "error" />
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Address:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-9">
                         <form:textarea class="form-control" rows="2" path="address"></form:textarea>
                           <form:errors path = "address" cssClass = "error" />
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Mobile:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <form:input class="form-control" type="text" path="mobNo"/>
                         
                      </div>
                      <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Email:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                          <form:input class="form-control" type="email" path="emailId"/>
                           <form:errors path = "emailId" cssClass = "error" />
                      </div>
                  </div>
               
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Department:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <select name="deptId" id="dept_Id" class="form-control" size="0">
                           <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <c:forEach var="depts" items="${departmentList}">
         <option value="<c:out value="${depts.deptid}" />">${depts.deptnm}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>
       
                    </div>
                     <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Designation:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <select name="desgId" id="design_Id" class="form-control" size="0">
                          <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <c:forEach var="desig" items="${designationList}">
         <option value="<c:out value="${desig.desgid}" />">${desig.desgnm}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>
      
                      </div>
                  </div>
                 
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Level:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-3">
                         <select name="userLevel" id="lvl_Id" class="form-control" size="0">
                            <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
         <c:forEach var="levelList" items="${levelList}">
             <option value="<c:out value="${levelList.sk}"/>">${levelList.ds}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>
       
                      </div>
                      <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Group:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <select name="grpId" id="grp_Id" class="form-control" size="0">
                             <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
        <c:forEach var="groupList" items="${groupList}">
         <option value="<c:out value="${groupList.grpid}" />">${groupList.grpnm}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>
       
                      </div>
                  </div>
                
                   <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Hint Question:</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <select name="hintId" id="que_Id" class="form-control" size="0">
                          <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <c:forEach var="questionList" items="${questionList}">
         <option value="<c:out value="${questionList.hintid}" />">${questionList.hintquestion}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>
       
                      </div>
                      <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Answer:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                          <form:input class="form-control" type="text" path="hintAns"/>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                 
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label form-control-label"></label>
                      <div class="col-lg-7">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Register">
                          <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form:form>
```

Can anybody help me out?

What i did wrong in this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `BindingResult` parameter has directly to follow the `@ModelAttribute` annotated class, which also needs to have the `@Valid` annotation. Also login validation should be ideally done in an `HandlerInterceptor` or even better use Spring Security instead of rolling your own solution.